Entity Framework Core Unidirectional many-to-many not working
I want to use a Unidirectional many-to-many relationship but I can't seem to get it to work.
I use EF Core 8.0.6 and recreated the example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#unidirectional-many-to-many) in a fresh Visual Studio project.
All Posts and all Tags are loaded but Post.List<Tag> remains empty. Am I missing something?
SQL:
CREATE TABLE "Posts" 
(
    "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Posts" PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE "Tags" 
(
    "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Tags" PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE "PostTag" 
(
    "PostId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "TagsId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_PostTag" PRIMARY KEY ("PostId", "TagsId"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_PostTag_Posts_PostId" 
        FOREIGN KEY ("PostId") REFERENCES "Posts" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_PostTag_Tags_TagsId" 
        FOREIGN KEY ("TagsId") REFERENCES "Tags" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
    
INSERT INTO Posts (Id) VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3);

INSERT INTO Tags (Id) VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3);

INSERT INTO PostTag (PostId, TagsId) 
VALUES (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0);

C#:
internal class DataBaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=*; Database=*; User Id=*; Password=*; TrustServerCertificate=true");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasMany(e => e.Tags).WithMany();
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; } = [];
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    DataBaseContext DBContext { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        var DBContext = new DataBaseContext();
        List<Post> posts = DBContext.Posts.ToList();
        List<Tag> tags = DBContext.Tags.ToList();
    }
}


You have to use Include.

@GertArnold That works, DBContext.Posts.Include(p => p.Tags).ToList(); Thank you! Why do I need to eager load this, but simple one-to-many relations load just fine? How can I determine when to eager load and when not to?

Many-to-many relationships don't have relationship fixup, a fact that's tactically ignored in the docs.

"How can I determine when to eager load and when not to?" If your code expects related info to be available then you should always eager load it. If lazy loading is not enabled and you rely on fix-ups in the one-to-many scenario, note that EF will only populate entities it happens to be tracking. This can often be inconsistent and incomplete. (I.e. only 2 of 4 children happen to be tracked at the time then only those two children will be auto-populated where eager loading ensures all four are loaded.)
